# How to convert questioner document to a xml format using java

Tags: java, xml, converters

My target is to make xml file from different questioner doc files.

For example.

```
Interviewer Name: Mr. K </br>
Street: BD 
Company: ABC

Mr. K: What is your Name? What is your father name?
Mr. R: My name is R.
          My father name is Z.
Mr. K: What is your hobby?
Mr. R: I like to play football.
       ......................
```

and so on.

Now, I want to parse it from doc file and convert to xml file. the xml file look like below

```xml
<interview>
  <information>
      <p>Interviewer Name: Mr. K</p>
      <p>Street: BD </p>
      <p>Company: ABC</p>
  </information>
  <question><p>What is your Name? What is your father name?</p></question>
  <answer>
<p>My name is R.</p>
<p>My father name is Z. </p>
</answer>
<question><p>What is your hobby?</p></question>
<answer>
   <p>I like to play football.</p>
   <p>.......</p>
 </answer>

</interview>
```

code here

I have used POI api to read doc file and DOM api to create XML. But my main problem is the
algorithm by which I can identify the questions, answer and the information block.
Could you give me some idea about that?

Answer (score 2):

I used JaxB once for this kind of problem.  You make a Java class that is the equivalent to your XML.  Then JaxB transforms an instance of that class to XML or vice versa.

Take a look at this:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: JAXB is a good solution for converting java classes to xml. But this requires parsing your document to get the content of your java class. The parsing process is the more exhausting topic. Applying JaxB is pretty straight forward.

Comment: yes, convert to XML and read Doc is not a problem. the problem is how can I automatically detect the question and answer from a document. the question is not only with a "?" mark. it may be stated in a declarative form as in "I was wondering if you are free at 8 am". I am facing difficultly in that case.

Comment: If you convert it to a Java object with JaxB (with the custom class you make), then you you can have a "getter" method that will grab the contents of the "question" tag.